# TiledMap wont render

Tags: libgdx

the code below keeps rendering a black screen...any ideas why? I put the base.tmx in the desktop folder and created it using tiled. did i put the .tmx in the wrong folder? its driving me nuts.

```
public class GameScreen extends ScreenAdapter {

OrthographicCamera camera;
TiledMap tiledmap;
TiledMapRenderer tiledMapRenderer;

public void show()
{
    camera=new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false);
    camera.update();
    tiledmap= new TmxMapLoader().load("base.tmx");
    tiledMapRenderer=new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(tiledmap);
}
public void render()
{
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    camera.update();
    tiledMapRenderer.setView(camera);
    tiledMapRenderer.render();
}
```

}

Comment: Can you please show the code that you set this screen to game also.

Comment: 'public class TownRPG extends Game {
 
 @Override
 public void create () {
  setScreen(new GameScreen());
 }

 
}'  You mean this?

Comment: Yes, it's ok. Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not setting width and height of your camera. Also you should override render method of ScreenAdapter correctly with delta parameter. This is the updated version of your code :

```
public class GameScreen extends ScreenAdapter {

OrthographicCamera camera;
TiledMap tiledmap;
TiledMapRenderer tiledMapRenderer;

    public void show()
    {
        float w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        float h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

        camera=new OrthographicCamera();
        camera.setToOrtho(false,w,h);
        camera.update();
        tiledmap= new TmxMapLoader().load("base.tmx");
        tiledMapRenderer=new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(tiledmap);
    }

    public void render(float delta)
    {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        camera.update();
        tiledMapRenderer.setView(camera);
        tiledMapRenderer.render();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your render method is wrong if it's not pseudo code. You are not overriding render method of ScreenAdapter, you don't have delta parameter in render method. Check this : https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/ScreenAdapter.html

Comment: So, your render method is not called from any class, you should override "render" method correctly.

Comment: you sir are a genius and a gentleman....if I could reach into the screen and give you a cookie, I would do so 10 times.

Comment: Not at all @YaserElsa, I have updated my code. Can you please upvote my answer if it's ok for you.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have enough points to do that :( sorry dude. Btw I have another question in regards to object collision on tiledmaps...think you can help me out?